# «Возможно» – тире или-с запятушонка?

Tags: запятые

Можете сказать, как правильно? Я ставлю паузу перед *наверное*, то есть предложение перед этим словом – это первая, отделная часть.

1. Он меня перед всеми отчитал – возможно, из-за того, что был злой, как волк.
2. Он меня перед всеми отчитал, возможно из-за того, что был злой, как волк.

Comment: возможно по-умолчанию вводное, но оно скорее всего может быть и наречием, тогда запятая нужна только для обособления оборота. А есть словари где оно еще сказуемое и частица https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/149/возможно . Так что запятки можно ставить или обособляя возможно  - Он меня перед всеми отчитал, возможно, из-за того, что был злой, как волк; или можно как наречие - Он меня перед всеми отчитал, возможно из-за того, что был злой, как волк. Тире, мне кажется, лишнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта оформления можно объяснить:

1. *Он меня перед всеми отчитал — **возможно, из-за того,** что был злой, как волк.*

**Присоединительная конструкция**: тире вместо запятой (подчеркнутая пауза), присоединяется придаточное предложение, возможно — вводное слово.

Пример у Розенталя **с запятой**: Всё это имеет для меня неизъяснимую прелесть, **может быть,** оттого, что я уже не увижу их (Г.);

2. *Он меня перед всеми отчитал, (это) **возможно из-за того**, что был злой, как волк.*

**Бессоюзная связь (БСП),** присоединительные отношения (присоединительная интонация без подчеркнутой паузы), возможно — сказуемое.

Comment: Если прошедшее, то надо "стало возможно"! Иначе неверно. Но честно говоря, второй вариант бредовый, просто вслушайтесь: *Он меня перед всеми отчитал, это стало возможно из-за того, что был злой, как волк.* Ну и "из-за того" при "возможно" без запятых слишком разговорно, нормально "благодаря тому".